# Unable to pass Excel worksheet to a function in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using VBA in an access application to create an Excel file. I am creating the excel application and worksheet just fine but when I try to pass that worksheet to another function, I get this error:

> Run-time error '438':
>   Object doesn't support this property or method

Here is the code where I set up my excel application:

```
Public Sub setUpExcel()
  Dim XLAPP As Excel.Application
  Set XLAPP = New Excel.Application
  XLAPP.Visible = True
  Dim WKB As Excel.Workbook
  Dim WKS As Excel.Worksheet, WKS2 As Excel.Worksheet

  Set WKB = XLAPP.Workbooks.Open(excelFile)

  Set WKS = WKB.ActiveSheet '.Worksheets(1)
  WKS.Range("A1").Value = "Test Value"
  WKS.Range("A1").Select
  WKS.Range("A1").Value = ""

  makeMasterPage (WKS) '<--WHERE I GET ERROR
End Sub
```

The call to makeMasterPage is where I get my error. Here is that function:

```
Private Sub makeMasterPage(ByRef WKS As Excel.Worksheet)
   ...
End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is access has no idea what a worksheet is. Try passing as object which will force late binding.

Comment: Well I am not really sure what I did but the error isn't coming up again. I do have Private Sub makeMasterPage(WKS As Worksheet) now instead of what I had before so perhaps that fixed it...

Comment: The sub is in your Access database, not in your Excel file, right, and the two subs are in the same module (since one is private)? If you've added the proper references, Access should understand the worksheet object as well as Excel does.

Comment: Also please note that if it's a subroutine, then you should not use parenthesis when calling it.... ie: `makeMasterPage WKS` should do what you want more effectively.

Comment: I was going to suggest WKS As Worksheet it will be passing a reference anyway.  Since makeMasterPage is private, in excel VBA and it might be the same for Access if the calling sub is not in the same module you would have to call with Application.Run "modulename.makeMasterPage", WKS